# What is "safe mode" and how does it affect RPC Commands?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, safemode

The [source code here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/bitcoinrpc.cpp#L223) has a list of RPC commands and a "okSafeMode" parameter.

What is the purpose of this SafeMode and how does it affect the usage of the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Bitcoin-Qt detects that something is seriously wrong with the network, it disables most RPC functionality in order to prevent automated Bitcoin sites from losing a lot of money due to network problems. (The okSafeMode functions are not disabled.) All versions since ~0.3 go into safe mode when the longest chain is invalid (illegal transaction, creating too much money, etc.). Upcoming versions will also go into safe mode when a large fork (valid or invalid) is in danger of overtaking the current chain.

Comment: I thought that the longest valid fork was in fact the "current chain".